# jQuery UI Autocomplete parsing json data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, autocomplete

I'm trying to add autocomplete to my search input, this is my json:

```
json={"explains":[],"count":15,"quotes":[{"exchange":"NMS","shortname":"Apple Inc.","quoteType":"EQUITY","symbol":"AAPL","index":"quotes","score":8.85572E7,"typeDisp":"Equity","longname":"Apple Inc.","isYahooFinance":true},{"exchange":"MEX","shortname":"APPLE INC","quoteType":"EQUITY","symbol":"AAPL.MX","index":"quotes","score":20671.0,"typeDisp":"Equity","longname":"Apple Inc.","isYahooFinance":true}]}
```

I am trying to create a table with  with each row the exchange,shortname, symbol I used this script:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response) {
                    //Fetch data
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "http://localhost:5000/search",
                        dataType : "json",
                        cache: false,
                        data : {
                            q : request.term
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            alert(data);
//How parse the data here to create the table?
                            response(data);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                            alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength : 2
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How parse the json and create the table with the elements? i am stuck here. Some help?

Comment: What exactly do you want displayed? Also what have you tried?

Comment: var obj=JSON.parse(data);
var one=obj.quotes[0].shortname;
how iterate here to get all 0...n values to insert in a dynamic table

Comment: You seem to be confusing autocomplete with a table